# Trying to create a dashboard in Kibana for API Manager under device section it is expecting the value for parameter host.os.type.keyword

Tags: wso2, kibana, wso2-api-manager, dashboard

Trying to create a dashboard in Kibana for API Manager under device section it is expecting the value for parameter host.os.type.keyword which is not available in our API Metric logs in WSO2 API Manager.

Can you please help us out.